# Unable to display the same format as was when entered into the database with PHP as back end

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I inserted and retrieved text to/from Mysql database the format remained same. But when I tried to insert a few lines of code and displayed them on the browser it lost the original "one below the other " format and appeared in a straight line as shown below. I am sure there must have been a smarter way to accomplish this. I have tried to locate answers on SO but couldn't find something that can address the issue mentioned here. I would like any advise/example on how to do it.

Format to be retained.

```
$myFile = "sampleFile.txt";

$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');

$myFileContents = fread($fh, 21);

fclose($fh);

echo $myFileContents;
```

As it appears straightline on the browser.

```
$myFile = "sampleFile.txt"; $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r'); $myFileContents = fread($fh, 21); fclose($fh); echo $myFileContents;
```

Comment: or this is a case of linefeed/carriage returns. Look at your html source; the breaks are in there alright. Are you really storing those codes in a db?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks. Sorry for the less clarity of my question. I basically wanted to insert pieces of code (for tutorial purposes as in w3schools.com but with very minimum features) into Database in a format as shown in my code above and display the same format. I would like to be more clear if you need me to be.

Comment: you can use `nl2br()`. seems like the solution for this. Like I said; if you view html source, you will see the linebreaks or add `\n` or `\r\n` if on windows when writing to the file/db.

Comment: @Fred-ii-. Excellent solution as nl2br() output the result the way I needed.

Comment: Great; I posted my answer for you below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As (I) stated in comments, you need to use the [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function.

This will show your codes as intended, one line underneath the other.

Answer (score 0):

Use the  tag or an element with the CSS property 
    white-space: pre;

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

It is a quick solution that works, 
however it still requires some server/client side tinkering to properly show any type of HTML to properly show up on a webpage.

HTML tag open and closing tags will mess up output for example, so you will probably need HTML Entities in PHP or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I shall check it out shortly.